# How to Use "zipWhen" With Conditions?

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor, spring-webflux

Hello I would like to know how to use the "zipwhen" function of the reactor project since it is not clear in the documentation.

My problem is the following I make a series of calls to Rest / Web services the issue is that as I have it now I always call all the services but I would like to parameterize so as not always to call all of them if it does not depend on the needs using zipwhen.

I don´t really know if is possible using zipwhen.

Something like :

I have a class service in which I make the calls to the different web services (since it is an example it is always the same but in fact it will be to n different web services)

```
@Service
public class FuenteRiesgoService {

    @Autowired
    SmartBearWsClient smartBearWsClient;

    public Mono<GetCurrentTimeResponse> fuenteWS1() {

        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            Random rn = new Random();
            System.out.println("Llamando a fuente WS1 ..... on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(rn.nextInt(50 - 1 + 1) + 1 * 10000);
            GetCurrentTimeResponse getCurrentTimeResponse = smartBearWsClient.getCurrentTime(new GetCurrentTime());
            System.out.println("Respuesta fuente WS1 " + getCurrentTimeResponse.getGetCurrentTimeResult() + " on "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return getCurrentTimeResponse;
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());

    }

    public Mono<GetCurrentTimeResponse> fuenteWS2(boolean call) {

        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            Random rn = new Random();
            System.out.println("Llamando a fuente WS2 ..... on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(rn.nextInt(50 - 1 + 1) + 1 * 10000);
            GetCurrentTimeResponse getCurrentTimeResponse = smartBearWsClient.getCurrentTime(new GetCurrentTime());
            System.out.println("Respuesta fuente WS2 " + getCurrentTimeResponse.getGetCurrentTimeResult() + " on "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return getCurrentTimeResponse;
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());

    }

public Mono<GetCurrentTimeResponse> fuenteWS3() {

    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        Random rn = new Random();
        System.out.println("Llamando a fuente WS3 ..... on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(rn.nextInt(50 - 1 + 1) + 1 * 10000);
        GetCurrentTimeResponse getCurrentTimeResponse = smartBearWsClient.getCurrentTime(new GetCurrentTime());
        System.out.println("Respuesta fuente WS3 " + getCurrentTimeResponse.getGetCurrentTimeResult() + " on "
                + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return getCurrentTimeResponse;
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());

}

public Mono<GetCurrentTimeResponse> fuenteWS4() {

    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        Random rn = new Random();
        System.out.println("Llamando a fuente WS4 ..... on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(rn.nextInt(50 - 1 + 1) + 1 * 10000);
        GetCurrentTimeResponse getCurrentTimeResponse = smartBearWsClient.getCurrentTime(new GetCurrentTime());
        System.out.println("Respuesta fuente WS4 " + getCurrentTimeResponse.getGetCurrentTimeResult() + " on "
                + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return getCurrentTimeResponse;
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());

}

}
```

With this return what it does is to call the 4 web services always

```
return fuenteRiesgoService.fuenteWS1()
    .zipWith(fuenteRiesgoService.fuenteWS2(), (a, b) -> {
    return " - WS1 : " + a.getGetCurrentTimeResult().toString() + " - WS2 : "
                + b.getGetCurrentTimeResult().toString();
}).zipWith(fuenteRiesgoService.fuenteWS3(), (a, b) -> {
    return a + " - WS3 : " + b.getGetCurrentTimeResult().toString();
}).zipWith(fuenteRiesgoService.fuenteWS4(), (a, b) -> {
    System.out.println("Fuentes obtenidas " + a + " - WS4 : " + b.getGetCurrentTimeResult().toString()
                + " on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return a + " - WS4 : " + b.getGetCurrentTimeResult().toString();
});
```

But what I want to do is to be able to call oneself and others not through parameters with zipwhen.

For example, call ws2 and ws4 but not ws3, so it does not do anything with the ws3

```
boolean callws2 = true;
boolean callws3 = false;
boolean callws4 = true;

return fuenteRiesgoService.fuenteWS1()
    .zipWhen(if(callws2 = true) -> fuenteRiesgoService.fuenteWS2(), (a, b) -> {
    return " - WS1 : " + a.getGetCurrentTimeResult().toString() + " - WS2 : "
                + b.getGetCurrentTimeResult().toString();
}).zipWhen(if(callws3 = true) -> fuenteRiesgoService.fuenteWS3(), (a, b) -> {
    return a + " - WS3 : " + b.getGetCurrentTimeResult().toString();
}).zipWhen(if(callws4 = true) -> fuenteRiesgoService.fuenteWS4(), (a, b) -> {
    System.out.println("Fuentes obtenidas " + a + " - WS4 : " + b.getGetCurrentTimeResult().toString()
                + " on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return a + " - WS4 : " + b.getGetCurrentTimeResult().toString();
});
```

Comment: could you explain a bit more about you're use case? In which cases the other services should not be called? timeout? error? or something that should be decided by programming logic? Does that programming logic depends on the result of one of those REST calls? Please be more explicit.

Comment: I tried to explain it better, I do not know if it's possible, it's an honor to answer Brian Clozel :) @BrianClozel

Answer (score 14):

Project Reactor provides many operators and it's sometimes hard to figure out which is the best solution - the functional, reactive mindset has a lot to do with this.

`zipWhen` is a specific operator that combines results, but unlike `zipWith`, you need to look at the first result before you can make the second call. Let's take an example here: preparing a holiday. You need to book a hotel before you can book a taxi to go there.

```
Mono<HotelBooking> first = bookHotel(startDate, EndDate);
// you need the chosen hotel location before you can book a taxi,
// but you still need both bookings in the end
Mono<Tuple2<HotelBooking, TaxiBooking>> result = first
    .zipWhen(booking -> bookTaxi(airport, booking.getLocation());
```

It seems your example doesn't require you to get information from intermediate results. If the logic is synchronous and non-blocking, regular application logic should be the preferred way.

```
Mono<String> result = fuenteRiesgoService.fuenteWS1();
if (callws2) {
  result = result.zipWith(fuenteRiesgoService.fuenteWS2(), combinatorFunction);
}
if (callws3) {
  result = result.zipWith(fuenteRiesgoService.fuenteWS3(), combinatorFunction);
}
return result;
```